# improving the CellEditor layout in gwt

Tags: gwt

I am using a gwt incubator table in our project. And I have a requirement to show one of the column text as a popup when the field is clicked on. The reason is the data could be little large and it does not look nice to resize the table columns to read the value in that column.

So, we thought if on clicking the attribute if we can show a popup with the text. I tried to achieve it using CellEditor as follows:

```
TextCellEditor cellEditor = new TextCellEditor() {
                @Override
                public boolean onAccept() { 
                    return true;
                }
            };

            cellEditor.setHeight("100px");
            columnDef.setCellEditor(cellEditor);
```

But the problem is the actual text box inside cell editor popup still does not increase in height. any other way by cell editor or some other way to show a pop up on either mouse over of that column or by clicking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nevermind instead of playing with celleditor what i did is added a small icon in the table column values field and added a popup on click listener